# Link SEDE page to specific site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

I am browsing the SEDE on the CiviCRM meta page. On the main page, I can click Visit Site and go to it:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But looking at that site's page, I can't see how to get to it. The CiviCRM meta text doesn't link back at all:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Please can there be a way to get to the site from this page?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/66 - clicking the logo for the site will now take you back. We could explicitly add a link as well...